# Why IList<T> inherits IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable again

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ienumerable

I have taken a look on [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) and [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) on MSDN by chance, and see that the definition of these two interfaces are:

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Notice that `ICollection<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`, that's okay. `IList<T>` inherits from `ICollection<T>`, but why `IList<T>` has to inherit `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` again?

Any there any reason for this?

Comment: I believe it is for compatibility since IEnumerable<T> came with version 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is generated that way so you can see what interfaces a type implements without having to follow transitive links through the interface inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I agree. There's no structural reason, except for clarity IMHO.

Comment: It is just the documentation. If you check the mscorlib library, for example with dotPeek then you can see, that in the IList<T> interface the interfaces are listed again like this:

Comment: Not really if you try to implement `ILIst<T>` you would indeed get and need two versions of the `GetEnumerator`

Comment: @V4Vendetta I believe you misunderstood the question

Comment: @280Z28 I guess you are right, maybe you can refer this in the answer http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/IList@cs/1305376/IList@cs